# Merge nested object using Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, lodash

I have an object, which look like this,

```
{"basket":
    [
        {
            "firmId":"27150190-3aa0-4740-a859-3e215d338a2b",
            "adisyonId":"35dca2a0-2c9a-4d8d-9b0e-1e146f7b900a","productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
            "product":
                {
                    "productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
                    "productCategoryId":"8ac4cb8c-86cb-4d23-8f01-639a7f6ac1be",
                    "productCategory":null,
                    "productName":"cola",
                    "price":8.00,
                    "st":true}},

        {
            "firmId":"4ac6dd14-798a-422f-8f3e-1ed06f5e8fb7",
            "adisyonId":"35dca2a0-2c9a-4d8d-9b0e-1e146f7b900a",
            "productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
            "product":
                {
                    "productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
                    "productCategoryId":"8ac4cb8c-86cb-4d23-8f01-639a7f6ac1be",
                    "productCategory":null,
                    "productName":"tea",
                    "price":1.00,
                    "st":true}}]};
```

I use that lodash.js then I want it as I want it to be in the example below.

```
{"basket":
    [
        {
            "product":
                {
                    "firmId":"27150190-3aa0-4740-a859-3e215d338a2b",
                    "productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
                    "productCategoryId":"8ac4cb8c-86cb-4d23-8f01-639a7f6ac1be",
                    "productCategory":null,
                    "productName":"cola",
                    "price":8.00,
                    "st":true}},

        {
            "product":
                {
                    "firmId":"4ac6dd14-798a-422f-8f3e-1ed06f5e8fb7",
                    "productId":"de37dce5-f8f9-4f54-900f-fbc90659b37d",
                    "productCategoryId":"8ac4cb8c-86cb-4d23-8f01-639a7f6ac1be",
                    "productCategory":null,
                    "productName":"tea",
                    "price":1.00,
                    "st":true}}]};
```

I tried this,

```
var list = [];
_.each(this.props.basket, function (item) {
    list.push(_.omit(item, 'firmId'));
    list.push(_.flatten(_.pick(item, 'product')));
});
var result = _.flatten(list);
console.log(result);
```

Its above code only give that first version, so I want to merge firmId and products on one object.

Thanks,

Comment: The objects in both your snippets are invalid JSON. Depending on the engine, only either the value of the first duplicate key or last duplicate key will exist in the resulting object.

Comment: Sure you aren't starting with an array of objects?

Comment: Same problem with expected results also...can't have duplicate keys in an object

Comment: I know first is invalid JSON because valid object length of 20, so i tried to wrote basic object for question. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @ByAvora but objects don't have length which leads me to believe you actually have an array of objects, not what is shown. Please take a few minutes to read through [mcve]

Comment: @ByAvora if you know the first is invalid JSON then you should know you can't claim that "I have an object, which look like this"

Comment: @PatrickRoberts i updated that post and object

Comment: @charlietfl 
I don't need to have a double key in an object, I just want to move the value in a parent object to a child object.

Comment: Fine but what you were showing was not valid or runnable

Comment: @charlietfl how can i solve that the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can do this as a simple map()

```
const list = this.props.basket.map(({firmId, product}) => {
   product.firmId = firmId;
   return {product};
})
```

Comment: well, how can i select just only product after map method, 
Is there a shorter solution than this?      list.map(t => t.urun) @charlietfl

Comment: Not sure what you are asking

Comment: your code return like this {product: {…}} i would like to return that {productId :"123123","productName":"blabla"....} so 
After applying your code it's going to be what I want doing again.  list.map(t => t.product) so Is there a shorter solution than this?

Comment: OK...was following the structure you showed in example.... change to `return product;`

Comment: ohh sorry thats my fold :) I couldn't see such a simple thing because I tried so hard to solve the problem. thanks.